# How to scrape/extract data from Esri ArcGIS from website

Tags: data-collection

I was trying to extract data from an ESRI map embedded in a website. The objective would be by introducing geographic coordinates to be able to access the values ​​present on the map.

I leave here a print of the map and the respective address. I just cannot understand which method I should use since the map is embedded in the site. What processes should I use?

*for academic purposes

https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/default.jsp

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is probably to just contact the site owner and ask if you can get a copy of the data. In any case, asking if it's OK to use their data would be polite, if not actually required. The mapservice does not contain a copyright notice, but that doesn't mean it's open data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I usually do is look at the requests made by the browser. Press F12 to open the 'developer tools', and then select the Network tab. (I'm not sure if the names are the same in different browsers, but they all behave quite similar in any case)

When zooming around the map, you will see many requests that go to server.arcgisonline.com and services.arcgisonline.com, these are just the (imagery) background tiles and can be ignored. When you zoom in sufficiently, you will also see requests like this:

https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png8&layers=show%3A1&bbox=-946807.1692328664%2C4890281.264462542%2C-931806.4024319208%2C4901364.633563878&bboxSR=102100&imageSR=102100&size=785%2C580&f=image

There are some things to note here:

1. A proxy is used (proxy.jsp). The actual ArcGIS service is in this case not accessible from outside, but only through this proxy. Everything you want to get from the service has to go through this
2. This is a request used to generate a PNG image of the current map extent for this particular service (note the part that says MapServer/export). If you need the actual data, you'll need to modify the request, see below
3. If you try to open this URL in a separate browser tab, it will give an error about an invalid 'referer'. The referer will be set by the browser to the URL of the current page. The easiest way to get around this is to use a tool such as Postman, and manually add a Referer header to the request

To get to the actual data (not an image) of this service, you need some knowledge about how to access an ArcGIS mapservice. In particular, you need to know how to query a layer: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-map-service-layer-.htm

Here's an example:

This service has 5 layers (Comércio, Habitação, Indústria, Serviços and Terrenos). Let's say you want data from the first one (index 0). A typical request would look like this: http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1 (Of course this needs to be prefixed with the proxy url, and properly escaped)

This example will return the data of the first layer of this service in JSON format (KMZ and geojson are also available) with a *where clause* of `1=1`, which basically means *everything*, but since this parameter is required you need to set it to something. Usually the number of returned records in a single request is limited by ArcGIS Server, so you'll only get 500 or 1000 records. If you need more, you should play around with the *where*, e.g. one request with `objectid<1000`, one with `objectid>=1000 and objectid<2000` etcetera.

Comment: Thank you very much, what a complete response ! 
When i add the Host key to Headers i can not get any response ! Why? sorry for the amount of doubts ...

Comment: My goal is to extract the coordinates of the respective polygons and their value, but I am managing to get it, regardless of introducing the header ... Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this field!

Comment: @JoãoSantos you should add an http header to the request with name *Referer* and value *https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/default.jsp* (note, SE removes https:// from the link text, but that should be include in the value)

Comment: With the key:Referer and Value:zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/default.jsp I received:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "details": [
            "Current proxy configuration settings do not allow requests which do not include a referer header."
        ],
        "message": "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied."
    }
}

Comment: I'm using the previous url/proxy -> https://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1

Comment: @JoãoSantos which tool do you use to execute the http request?

Comment: Postman with interceptor @Berend Accept my connection at linkedin please and i send u one print! Thank You very much, you are an expert !

Comment: @JoãoSantos I declined your Linkedin invitation because outside this question, I don't think we know each other that well. Nothing personal. Just to make sure we're talking about the same thing: In Postman, open the request and click on the *Headers* tab (it's between Authorization and Body). You'll find a number of headers already populated; add one below those and type Referer in the KEY column and https ://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/default.jsp in the VALUE column (I've intentionally typed a space before : so it will remain visible in this comment. Remove that space)

Comment: If I leave out that header, I get the same error message as you did. If I include it, the request works and I get a response from ArcGIS Server

Comment: No worries, I understand! 
I'm blowing my mind,  I just can't understand why I can't get a response from ARCgis. I am doing exactly everything as you say and it just doesn't work. You are performing the get request to: https ://zonamentopf.portaldasfinancas.gov.pt/simulador/proxy.jsp?http ://ags/arcgis/rest/services/SIMIMI/SIMIMI/MapServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1    ?

Comment: Also when i click the Headers tab I don't have any populated headers ... that is suposed?

Comment: I finally made it, it was the version of the postman who was in conflict!

Comment: Last question, the values associated with polygons comes where? I don't know if I'm explaining myself well, that is, we have a set of points that complete a polygon. For each polygon, a value of 0 <x <1 is assigned, which is shown in the images. Is this value included in the request?

Comment: @JoãoSantos I suppose you mean the attribute values? By default only a single so-called Display Field is returned by arcgis server. To return other fields, add an `outfields` parameter to the query. For example `outfields=field1,field2` or `outfields=*` to return everything. See the link in my answer.